# Can't read lines from a .txt file with Python because of decoding error

Tags: python, decode

I want to read in a .txt file line by line, but error occurred, saying ***'gbk' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 5195: illegal multibyte sequence***.

I don't quite understand this. Are there multiple ways to decode a .txt file and thus I need to specify something? Or should I convert the .txt file somehow?

```
import urllib2

fname = urllib2.urlopen("https://www.gutenberg.org/files/1661/1661-0.txt")
for line in fname:
    print(line[0])
```

BTW, I have tried downloading the .txt file and opening from local drive. Same problem. Have anybody seen this before?

Comment: Please provide the entire error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this if you are using python3:

```
import urllib2

response = urllib2.urlopen("https://www.gutenberg.org/files/1661/1661-0.txt")

for line in response.decode('utf-8'):
    print(line[0])
```

or try request package

```
import requests

response = requests.get("https://www.gutenberg.org/files/1661/1661-0.txt").text
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the accepted answer:

### Use `urllib.request` for Python 3

If you are using Python 3, don't use `urllib2`. Use the built-in `urllib.request` module instead (no need to install anything).

See the notes [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html):

> Note: The urllib2 module has been split across several modules in Python 3 named urllib.request and urllib.error.

To read the book text to a variable:

```
import urllib.request

book_url = "https://www.gutenberg.org/files/1661/1661-0.txt"

response = urllib.request.urlopen(book_url)
book_text = response.read().decode('utf-8')
```

Or, to print out the entire book to the terminal:

```
import urllib.request

book_url = "https://www.gutenberg.org/files/1661/1661-0.txt"

with urllib.request.urlopen(book_url) as f:
    print(f.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

### The `requests` Package

As the accepted answer notes, you can install and use the `requests` package for a higher-level HTTP interface. However, it still needs to handle the encoding explicitly:

```
import requests

book_url = "https://www.gutenberg.org/files/1661/1661-0.txt"
r = requests.get(book_url)
r.encoding = 'utf-8'
response = r.text
print(response)
```

Without the explicit instruction to use UTF-8, the results may handle certain characters incorrectly, such as Microsoft so-called smart/curly quotes. You may get something like this...

```
Lestrade laughed. âI am afraid that I am still a sceptic,â he said.
```

...when you should get this:

```
Lestrade laughed. “I am afraid that I am still a sceptic,” he said.
```

### Why is the Explicit Encoding Needed?

The URL we are accessing points to a Project Gutenberg web page displaying the text of a novel. However, when I open this page in my browser, the data is not displayed correctly. For example, I see this:

```
Lestrade laughed. â€œI am afraid that I am still a sceptic,â€ he said.
```

Towards the top of the web page, we see the following:

```
Title: The Adventures of Sherlock Holmes

Author: Arthur Conan Doyle

Release Date: November 29, 2002 [EBook #1661]
Last Updated: May 20, 2019

Language: English

Character set encoding: UTF-8
```

So, the body of the text is telling us that the page is apparently encoded using UTF-8.

However if we inspect the document (e.g. using Forefox's "inspect element" tools), we see this:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resource://content-accessible/plaintext.css">
</head>
```

There is no [encoding](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_charset.asp) specified:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

We therefore have to explicitly handle this ourselves when we process the response text. This ensures Python will handle the data correctly.

Once the data leaves Python (e.g. if it is written to a file, or displayed in a terminal) then users of that data (e.g. file readers, terminal displays) will need to ensure that they also use the correct encoding when handling the data.

Comment: Wow... this clarifies everything. I don't even know what to say! Thanks!